# Error using if statement on VBA Collection

Tags: vba, excel

I set up a series of VBA Collections and I'm comparing a cell value against the value in the collection, but sometimes the collection item does not exist, is there a function that would help this code run when one of the items is undefined:

```
Select Case Range("A" & ActiveCell.row).Value

            Case Is = item1.Item(1)

            item1.Add ActiveCell.Value

            Case Is = item2.Item(1)

            item2.Add ActiveCell.Value

            Case Is = item3.Item(1)

            item3.Add ActiveCell.Value

            Case Is = item4.Item(1)

            item4.Add ActiveCell.Value

            Case Is = item5.Item(1)

            item5.Add ActiveCell.Value

        End Select
```

In this case item5.Item(1) is undefined.

Comment: You might need a proper [Error Handling method](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) to trap the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Error handler, here the most easy one :

```
    On Error GoTo Handler

    Select Case Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        Case Is = item1.Item(1)
            item1.Add ActiveCell.Value
        Case Is = item2.Item(1)
            item2.Add ActiveCell.Value
        Case Is = item3.Item(1)
            item3.Add ActiveCell.Value
        Case Is = item4.Item(1)
            item4.Add ActiveCell.Value
        Case Is = item5.Item(1)
            item5.Add ActiveCell.Value
    End Select

Handler:
MsgBox "Item not found"
Exit Sub 'Function
```

Comment: I know how to use on error resume next, but wouldn't it just trigger the next line of code? IE if Item5 is undefined (the Case Is = item5.Item(1) line triggers an error) wouldn't the code go on to add the activecell.value to item 5? Or would it go to the end of the select statement?

Comment: I'm AFC (computer) so I can't test in debug (click on the left gray bar to display a red line that will stop code execution so that you can see what is happening) and answer for sure but I would say it'll go to the next `Case Is...` . Anyway it won't work either as your object is not defined. Better solution, I changed it to a `GoTo` statement that will work but skip other tests. Last part of code isn't format as mobile app is super slow to load edits...